# How to use netrw-C?

Tags: vim, netrw

I recently stubled upon a feature in netrw that's called `netrw-C`. From the docs:

```
SETTING EDITING WINDOW                  *netrw-C* {{{2

One may select a netrw window for editing with the "C" mapping, or by setting
g:netrw_chgwin to the selected window number.  Subsequent selection of a file
to edit (|netrw-cr|) will use that window.

Related topics:         |netrw-cr|
Associated setting variables:   |g:netrw_chgwin|
```

I've managed to achieve the described behavior by manually setting
`g:netrw_chgwin` but I couldn't understand or find how that "C" mapping works.

Yes, I could just map

```
:let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr()
```

but I'm curious how the original `netrw-C` mapping works.

**Does anybody know how to use the "C" mapping described in the docs?**

Comment: Haha. I've been scratching my head for 3 years about that mapping without ever thinking about asking anybody.

Comment: netrw is designed to support having multiple windows with netrw directory displays showing.  Pressing "C" in one of those netrw windows will make it the preferred editing window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inside netrw the `C` mapping looks like its just mapped to

```
:let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr()
```

If you do a `:map C` you will get the output

```
n  C           *@:let g:netrw_chgwin= winnr()<CR>
```

From [`:h map-listing`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-listing)

```
Just before the {rhs} a special character can appear:
    *       indicates that it is not remappable
    @       indicates a buffer-local mapping
```

So `C` is the same as `:let g:netrw_chgwin= winnr()<CR>` that is just local to the netrw buffer.

Comment: Thank you, good to know that `:map` shows the current mapping.